# Difference between Functions and polynomial equations

Tags: functions

Why the function
$f(x) = x-5 $
is not equal to the function
$g(x) = \frac{x^2-25}{x+5}, x\ne-5$
Where can we say the equation are same i.e. $x-5$ and $\frac{x^2-25}{x+5}$, in case these were not any functions.
As $\frac{x^2-25}{x+5}$ is same as $x-5$.

Comment: I upvoted to partially reverse the anonymous downvotes, which I disagree with for two reasons: (1) If you are going to downvote a new user's query, I think it is reasonable to tell him why, so he can try to improve his query. (2) I can only think of two reasons that the query may have been downvoted: (2a) Poor formatting -  If that was the reason, why not simply cite the mathJax article and give him a chance to edit the query. ...see next comment

Comment: (2b) No work shown - my opinion, which seems to be in the minority, is that since the query involved questioning a definition or interpretation, as opposed to attacking/solving a math problem, there isn't really work for the OP to show.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks dear but still my question is understandable by someone that's why 5 answers are already given . So why they downvote

Comment: I didn't downvote, I upvoted to partially reverse other downvotes.  I don't think that the question should have been downvoted at all.  I tried to make this clear in my previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=x-5\\g(x)=\frac{x^2-25}{x+5}=\frac{(x-5)(x+5)}{x+5}$$

If $x\neq -5$, then we can simplify $g(x)$, so that $$g(x)=x-5$$

So both $f(x),g(x)$ are the same on the domain $(-\infty,-5)\cup(-5,\infty)$. However, if we also include $-5$ in our domain, we will get:

- $f(-5)=-10$
- $g(-5)=\frac{0}{0}$

The last value is undefined, and so they don't agree.

If you were to dra both $f(x),g(x)$ then the only difference would be that $g(x)$ makes a "jump" at $x=-5$.

Often this is drawn as follows:

[image]

Comment: But if they were not functions but just polynomial expressions can we say that both the expressions are equal.

Comment: That's a good question, and it really depends on your definition of "equality". If you only consider them as elements, without thinking about $x$ as a variable, then in some sense, yes.

Comment: oh that means suppose, if  there is a problem or question in which the expression were created for specific purpose and x should not be variable but a single element to fit with the condition of the problem then the expression are equal

Answer (score 0):

$g(x)$ is not defined at $x=-5$. But $f(x)$ is defined at every point. So you see the domains of the functions are different.

Comment: why is this downvoted?

Comment: Hey dear but as we simplify the "x²" expression we actually get x-5 . So the "x²" expression  is actually x-5 . My question is if we can't say the function is identical but can we say the expression are equal or the expressions can be termed like any numbers so can we say the number are identical. Or what other term can we use to say the expression are equal not the functions

Answer (score 0):

Because $\;x-5\;$ is defined in the whole real line $\;\Bbb R\;$, whereas $\;\cfrac{x^2-25}{x+5}\;$ isn't defined at $\;x=-5\;$, i.e.: it is defined only at $\;\Bbb R\setminus\{-5\}\;$.

Remember: two identical *functions* must (necessary condition) have the very same definition domain.

Comment: Hey dear but as we simplify the "x²" expression we actually get x-5 . So the "x²" expression  is actually x-5 . My question is if we can't say the function is identical but can we say the expression are equal or the expressions can be termed like any numbers so can we say the number are identical. Or what other term can we use to say the expression are equal not the functions

Comment: @Debakant "Dear"? ... Anyway, I've no idea how you mean to simplfy $\;x^2\;$ ...what is simplified is the thole expression in the numerator with the whole expression in the denominator. And the explanation why can't they be identical is there.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have written $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is that these are identical functions when $x\ne -5$. Since there is a disagreement at one point of the solution , $(x-5)$ and $\frac{x^2-25}{x+5}$ are non-identical.

Comment: Hey dear but as we simplify the "x²" expression we actually get x-5 . So the "x²" expression  is actually x-5 . My question is if we can't say the function is identical but can we say the expression are equal or the expressions can be termed like any numbers so can we say the number are identical. Or what other term can we use to say the expression are equal not the functions

Comment: You can cancel a factor up and down or on LHS and RHS only if the factor itself is non-zero. So the moment you are doing so called factorization are assuming $(x+5)=\ne 0.$  Next, in this equation: $2(x+5)=3(x+5)$ if you cancel $(x+5)$ you get $2=3.$